# What and where is the object created in the Client class in discord.py?

Tags: python, class, object, discord, discord.py

I am trying to understand how Client.event works in discord.py. This is the source code for the event method.

```
def event(self, coro):
    # Validation we don't need to worry about
    setattr(self, coro.__name__, coro)
    return coro
```

According to what I understand, a coroutine is passed into the event function and an attribute of the object is created with name same as the name of the coroutine and the value equal to the output of coroutine. What I don't understand is that what is the object we are talking about?

[Here](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/async/discord/client.py) is the source code for discord.py and I am unable to figure out where an object is being created. Please help.

Also, since a coroutine is taken as an argument, does it mean that only function which are preceded by async can be passed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usage of this is

```
client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    print("Message received")

client.run("token")
```

`event` registers the call-back by assigning to the `on_message` attribute of `client`.  So the two arguments to `event` are `client` and `on_message`.

`client` has other code that calls those coroutines. The default ones don't do much, but you can replace them to provide the logic for your bot.  (This is called event-driven programming if you want to do some more research)

Technically this decorator doesn't check if the passed `coro` is a coroutine, but the code that uses it later expects that, so will fail if that isn't true.

By the way, you're looking at an old branch of the code. [The newest code](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/discord/client.py#L873) isn't much different for this decorator, but is for others.

Comment: Is `client` an argument of event or an object of class `client` is an argument of event. Because self refers to the object and not to the class...

Comment: So we declare the object in our own code and it's not declared in the source code. Right?

Comment: `client.event` is the `event` method of the object `client`.  When you call a method of an object, the object itself is automatically bound to the first argument.  They're then using that bound method as a decorator, which means that the second argument of the method is the `on_message` coroutine

Comment: Yes.  The source code creates a class.  Our code creates an instance of that class, which has the methods described in the source code.